# Identify high memory process .NET

Tags: .net, performance, memory, process

My application creates multiple process and print requests goes through each of these process(es). Say, If i send 500 requests, the memory of the process gets increased and it prints all the requests. But the issue is, the memory doesn't come down even after the job is done. Hence, is there a way to identify whether the process is processing currently or i need to restart the process after completion of the job.

Thanks,
Vinoth.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to debug your code to see what memory errors you've left in there. there are many .NET memory leak tools available, run one of your processes through one of these.

Don't think that just becuase you have a garbage collector all your memory problems are solved, you still need to think about memory - more so than before, I find.

Some leak checking tools:

- [Memprofiler](http://memprofiler.com/)
- [Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)
- [Allocation Profiler](http://support.smartbear.com/articles/aqtime/net-allocation-profiler/)

Comment: Thanks, since this was a pre-existing code which i took over, i never debugged the code. I'll check on anyone of the above tool and will get back.